# Container for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to create a Mongo container with docker desktop on Windows 10. I'm having a lot of issues...
After installing Docker, I've shared C: on settings and I wrote this command on cmd:

```
docker run --name mongodb -v c:\tfg:data\db -d -p 27057:27017 mongo
```

It worked fine, but when I reboot, I can't connect from robomongo. 
Putting `docker ps -a`, I can see my container, but the ports column is empty:

[image: docker ps]

[docker logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSCDF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Status exited means that container in stopped.

```
docker start mongodb
```

Comment: Done, but it still not working. Situation is the same on docker ps -a

Comment: Try to look on this: https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/74#issuecomment-238918488
Seems like its your situation =)

Comment: Thanks for helping Qteb. I've now other issue: Unable to find image 'mongodb:3.3' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for mongodb, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.